# EDMX/ EF Remove Existing primary key column and add new column with primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edmx

I have folowwing scenario in ASP.net MVC - code first

```
[Table("api")]
public class Api
{
   [Column("Id")]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column("api_key")]
   public string ApiKey { get; set; }

   public virtual BookingPluginConfig BookingPluginConfig { get; set; }
}

public class BookingPluginConfig
{
   [Key,ForeignKey("Api")] 
   public int ApiId { get; set; }

   public virtual Api Api { get; set; }
}
```

1. Currently "Api" table to "BookingPluginConfig" have one to one relationship - I want to change it to one to many
2. 'BookingPluginConfig' table has

   ```
   [Key,ForeignKey("Api")]                
   public int ApiId { get; set; }
   ```

   I want to remove this column which is the primary key, and I want to add new column as the primary key (auto increment)

   Currently this 'ApiId ' is primary key as well foreign key. I want to remain ''ApiId '' is foreign key but not as primary key

I have already many data in existing table

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your modified BookingPluginConfig class:

```
public class BookingPluginConfig
{
  [Key(), Required]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Api")] 
  public int ApiId { get; set; }

  public virtual Api Api { get; set; }
}
```

Navigation property, which is the only change, in the API class:

```
//one to many relation to BookingPluginConfig
public virtual ICollection<BookingPluginConfig> BookingPluginConfigs { get; set; }
```

That's all you need to add a new primary key and define relation. Take back up of database if you want, add migration and update database.